# Bounded vs Uniformly Bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am looking for an example of a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ where each $f_n$ is bounded but the sequence is not uniformly bounded. How about $f_n(x) = x-1/n$ on $[1, \infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

A sequence of real-valued functions is uniformly bounded if there exists a constant $M\in \mathbb R$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x\in \mathbb R$.

Consider the functions $f_n(x)=n$. Clearly each of them is bounded (as it is a constant function), however, the functions are not uniformly bounded as the sequence $\{n\}$ is unbounded.

In the example you mentioned each of the functions is actually unbounded on the domain $[1,\infty)$, so it does not work.